# Check if file is not at the same folder using WMI

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

I'm using script which is looking for specified file in local disk. When it finds the file, it renames/removes files which are close to specified file. (I mean at the same directory, etc)

Sample code:

```
Sub RenameFolder( oldName, newName )
    Dim filesys
    Set filesys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If filesys.FolderExists( oldName ) Then
        filesys.MoveFolder oldName, newName
    End If
End Sub

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Filename = 'myfile' and Extension = 'exe'")

For Each objFile in colFiles

RenameFolder objFile.Drive & objFile.Path & "files\test",  objFile.Drive & objFile.Path & "files\test_old"
```

I want to add a condition, which will check if in the same directory as `myfile.exe`, there is another file called `otherfile.exe`.

If it is there - don't do anything, else - rename specified folder like in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [FileExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t(v=vs.84).aspx) method. Here's how I'd suggest you use it in your code:

```
Sub RenameFolder( oldName, newName )
    Dim filesys
    Set filesys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If filesys.FolderExists( oldName ) Then
        filesys.MoveFolder oldName, newName
    End If
End Sub

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Filename = 'myfile' and Extension = 'exe'")

For Each objFile in colFiles
    If Not filesys.FileExists(objFile.Drive & objFile.Path & "otherfile.exe") Then
        'No else clause needed since we are checking if the file _doesn't_ exist.
        RenameFolder objFile.Drive & objFile.Path & "files\test",  objFile.Drive & objFile.Path & "files\test_old"
    End If
Next
```

EDIT: Changed my example to work directly in asker's code.

Comment: But my code is looking for myfile.exe at the whole disk (i dont know what is the path of file until scirpt will find it). Your scirpt 'know' path of that file.

Comment: I've modified my example to work specifically with your code. Give that a shot @krysteksulek.